# Phonegap 2.4.0 - NetworkStatus alert

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to learn phonegap using the "PhoneGap Mobile Application Development Cookbook", published by PACKT publishing. Chapter 2 discusses file systems and this seems to be giving some errors. I copied the sample code and I get the following error:

[image]

"NetworkStatusxxxxxxxxxx"] (the number is different every time). 
I've been looking for a solution for several hours now, but without success, who can help?!

My code:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
```

File Download

```
var downloadDirectory;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);

function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(
        LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 
        0, 
        onFileSystemSuccess, 
        null
    );

    x$('#download_btn').on( 'click', function(e) {
        download();
    });
}

function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory('my_downloads',{create:true},
        function(dir) {
            downloadDirectory = dir;
        },fail);
}

function fail(error) {
    x$('#message').html('We encountered a problem: ' + error.code);
}

function download() {
    var fileURL = document.getElementById('file_url').value;
    var localFileName = getFilename(fileURL);

    x$('#message').html('Downloading ' + localFileName);

    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    fileTransfer.download(fileURL, downloadDirectory.fullPath + '/' + localFileName, 
        function(entry){
            x$('#message').html('Download complete. File saved to: ' + entry.fullPath);
        }, 
        function(error){
            alert("Download error source " + error.source);
        }
    );
}

// Obtain the filename
function getFilename(url) {
   if (url) {
      var m = url.toString().match(/.*\/(.+?)\./);
      if (m && m.length > 1) {
         return m[1] + '.' + url.split('.').pop();
      }
   }
   return "";
}
</script>
```

```
<input type="text"      id="file_url"       value="http://blogs.adobe.com/adobeingovernment/files/2012/07/phonegap.jpg" />
<input type="button"    id="download_btn"   value="Download" />

<div id="message"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This generally happens if there's an error loading the phonegap javascript file. One thing that has bit me multiple times is using the wrong `cordova.js` file -- if you're building an Android application, you have to use the Android generated `cordova.js` file, and the same applies to iOS applications.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you are using the android version of cordova.js in your cordova ios project. Create a fresh ios cordova project, copy cordova-x.x.x.js from the created project and place in your existing project replacing the already existing cordova-x.x.x.js file. Then, clean the project from Xcode and build again. Voila! no alerts from now on.